# Green's theorem and identities.

Tags: analysis, greens-theorem

Using Green's formula we will prove that

$\int\limits_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \,dS = \iint\limits_D \Delta u \,dx\,dy.$

Let $D$ be the region for which Green's theorem holds and $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let us denote the unit external tangent vector as $n$, i.e. if $\sigma(t)=(\sigma_1(t),\sigma_2(t))$ is a parameterization of the boundary $\partial D$ consistent with Green's theorem, then
$${n}=\dfrac{(\sigma_2^{'}(t),\sigma_1^{'}(t))}{||\sigma^{'}(t)||},$$
where $||\sigma^{'}(t)||=\sqrt{\sigma_1^{'}(t)^2+\sigma_2^{'}(t)^2}$,

$\sigma:(a,b)\rightarrow \partial D.$

Let's calculate the directional derivative
$$\left.\frac{d}{dS}u((x,y)+s_n)\right|_{s=0}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot n_1 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot n_2=\langle\nabla u,n\rangle,$$
where $n=(n_1,n_2)$ and $\nabla u = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y})$.
We have that
$$\langle\nabla u,n\rangle=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\sigma_2^{'}(t)}{||\sigma^{'}(t)||} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{-\sigma_1^{'}(t)}{||\sigma^{'}(t)||},$$
so
$$\int\limits_{\partial D} \langle\nabla u,n\rangle \, dS = \int\limits_a^b \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\sigma(t))\cdot \frac{\sigma_2^{'}(t)}{||\sigma^{'}(t)||} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\sigma(t))\cdot \frac{-\sigma_1^{'}(t)}{||\sigma^{'}(t)||}  \right)\cdot ||\sigma^{'}(t)|| \, dt=$$
$$=\int\limits_a^b \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\sigma(t)) {\sigma_2^{'}(t)} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\sigma(t)){\sigma_1^{'}(t)}  \right) \,dt= 
\int\limits_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,dy - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\,dx\,.$$
Applying Green's theorem for the last integral, we obtain:
$$\int\limits_{\partial D} \langle\nabla u,n\rangle \, dS =\int\limits_D \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x}\right)\,dx\,dy\,.$$

**How to similarly prove another equality?**

**$\iint\limits_D v\Delta u \,dx\,dy=-\iint\limits_D \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right) \,dx\,dy + \int\limits_{\partial D} v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\, dS$**

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $v\nabla^2u=\nabla \cdot (v\nabla u)-\nabla u\cdot \nabla v$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\iint_D v\nabla^2u\,dx\,dy&=\iint_D \left(\nabla \cdot (v\nabla u)-\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\right)\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\iint_D \nabla \cdot (v\nabla u)\,dx\,dy-\iint_D \nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=-\iint_D \nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,dx\,dy+\oint_{\partial D}\hat vn\cdot \nabla u\,ds\\\\
&=-\iint_D \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy+\oint_{\partial D}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,ds
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.